# How to launch Node Red and go to a specific flow dynamically?

Tags: node-red

We are using Node-red for a new project where our each UI button should point to a specific 'Node-red flow'.

However, I am unable to find how to point different buttons to different Node-red flow.  Node-red is launched using an URL and going to any flow will not change the URL, so I cannot assign each button different URLs.

Can anybody help me to understand how to launch Node-red and go to a specific flow dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean to change which flow (tab) is displayed in the Node-RED editor.

If that is the case there is no way to jump to a specific flow (tab) at this time. It is on the list of things to add, but there is no outlook as to when it might be implemented.

EDIT:
It is now possible to jump to specific tabs in the editor using the html fragment syntax. Each flow(tab) has a unique ID similar to this `1fbb6911.912587`, you can access that flow with a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:1880/#flow/1fbb6911.912587
```

To find the ID just click on a tab and the URL bar in your browser should be updated to match

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you please let me know if this can be somehow achieved using custom code may be?  Any pointers in this regard is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is most likely possible, but you'll have to go look at the code yourself to work out how. If you get it to work please read the Node-RED contribution guidelines on Github about how to contribute it back to the community.

Comment: Thanks for you time.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to access speciffic flow but not from the editor, but from UI page?

Comment: @David the original question is about the editor, ask a new question and include a lot more detail about what you want to do, because at it stands what you are asking makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

your will need the dashboard nodes.   In it is a node called Control UI.  I simply place a button (from same library) on the screen, set the payload to the name of the tab I want it to jump to and wire it to the Control UI node. I was able to make a 4 page workflow process that takes the user through calibrating a pump's output.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the Dashboard UI, it is specifically about the editor.